# Tkinter broke interface

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, queue, python-multithreading

I created a program that check ping of devices in a lan, the code works great at the begin, but when work more than 30 minutes (aprox) the interface starts to failure and stops to work, the console doesn't report any problem, this is the code that creates the structure of tyhe inteface:

```py
def update_interface_on_tab_change(self, event):
        self.hmi = threading.Thread(target = self.update_interface())
        self.hmi.start()
    
    def update_interface(self):
        try:
            try:
                data = self.ping_queue.get_nowait()
            except queue.Empty:
                return self.update_interface
            
            for tab in self.tab_control.tabs():
                self.tab_control.forget(tab)
            for pos_tab, seccion in data:
                nombre_seccion = seccion["nombre"]
                lineas = seccion["lineas"]
                tab = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)
                self.tab_control.add(tab, text=nombre_seccion)
                lineas_frame = ttk.Frame(tab)
                lineas_frame.pack(expand=True, fill="both", padx=3, pady=5) 

                n = 0  # Var control column on grid
                for idx_linea, linea in enumerate(lineas):
                    nombre_linea = linea["nombre_linea"]
                    equipos = linea["equipos"]

                    # Create the frame of production line
                    linea_frame = ttk.Frame(lineas_frame, borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
                    linea_frame.grid(row=0, column=n, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="n") 
                    n += 1

                    # Create name of production line
                    linea_label = ttk.Label(linea_frame, text=f"{nombre_linea}", font=("Arial", 14, "bold"))

                    distance = 1
                    idx = 0
                    pos = 0
                    for idy, equipo in enumerate(equipos):
                        if idy==32:
                            pos+=1
                            idx += 5*pos
                        idy -= pos*32
                        
                        host = equipo["host"]
                        ip = equipo["ip"]
                        status_color = equipo["status_color"]

                        equipo_label_text = f"{host}"
                        equipo_label = ttk.Label(linea_frame, text=equipo_label_text, font=("Arial", 11, "bold"))
                        equipo_label.grid(row=idy + 1, column=idx+0, padx=5, pady=distance, sticky="w")

                        if status_color == "green":

                            if host[0:3] == "BCL" or host[0:8] == "SCALANCE":
                                ip_label = tk.Label(linea_frame, text=ip, cursor="hand2", fg="blue" if status_color == "green" else "black", font=("Helvetica", 10, "underline", "bold"))
                                ip_label.grid(row=idy + 1, column=idx+1, padx=5, pady=distance, sticky="w")
                                ip_label.bind("<Button-1>", open_browser_with_ip)

                            elif host[0:3] =="PAD":
                                ip_label = tk.Label(linea_frame, text=ip, fg="black" if status_color == "green" else "black",font=("Arial", 10, "bold"))
                                ip_label.grid(row=idy + 1, column=idx+1, padx=5, pady=distance, sticky="w")
                                VNC_button = tk.Button(linea_frame, text="VNC viewer",  command= lambda ip=ip: threading.Thread(target = vnc_connection_bat, args = ([ip]), daemon=True).start())
                                VNC_button.grid(row=idy + 1, column=idx+2, padx=5, pady=distance, sticky="w")
                            
                            elif host[0:6]=="MASTER" or host[0:3] == "GRC":
                                ip_label = tk.Label(linea_frame, text=ip, fg="black" if status_color == "green" else "black", font=("Arial", 10, "bold"))
                                ip_label.grid(row=idy + 1, column=idx+1, padx=5, pady=distance, sticky="w")
                                CmRc_button = tk.Button(linea_frame, text="CmRc viewer",  command= lambda ip=ip: threading.Thread(target = cmrc_connection_bat, args = ([ip]), daemon=True).start())
                                CmRc_button.grid(row=idy + 1, column=idx+2, padx=5, pady=distance, sticky="w")

                            elif (host[0:3] != "BCL" and host[0:3] != "PAD" and host[0:6] !="MASTER"):
                                ip_label = tk.Label(linea_frame, text=ip, fg="black", font=("Arial", 10, "bold"))
                                ip_label.grid(row=idy + 1, column=idx+1, padx=5, pady=distance, sticky="w")

                        else:

                            if host[0:3] == "BCL" or host[0:8] == "SCALANCE":
                                ip_label = tk.Label(linea_frame, text=ip, cursor="hand2", fg="blue" if status_color == "green" else "grey", font=("Helvetica", 10, "underline", "bold"))
                                ip_label.grid(row=idy + 1, column=idx+1, padx=5, pady=distance, sticky="w")


                            elif host[0:3] =="PAD":
                                ip_label = tk.Label(linea_frame, text=ip, fg="black" if status_color == "green" else "black",font=("Arial", 10, "bold"))
                                ip_label.grid(row=idy + 1, column=idx+1, padx=5, pady=distance, sticky="w")
                                VNC_button = tk.Button(linea_frame, text="VNC viewer", state="disabled", command= lambda ip=ip: threading.Thread(target = vnc_connection_bat, args = ([ip]), daemon=True).start())
                                VNC_button.grid(row=idy + 1, column=idx+2, padx=5, pady=distance, sticky="w")
                            
                            elif host[0:6]=="MASTER" or host[0:3] == "GRC":
                                ip_label = tk.Label(linea_frame, text=ip, fg="black" if status_color == "green" else "black", font=("Arial", 10, "bold"))
                                ip_label.grid(row=idy + 1, column=idx+1, padx=5, pady=distance, sticky="w")
                                CmRc_button = tk.Button(linea_frame, text="CmRc viewer", state="disabled", command= lambda ip=ip: threading.Thread(target = cmrc_connection_bat, args = ([ip]), daemon=True).start())
                                CmRc_button.grid(row=idy + 1, column=idx+2, padx=5, pady=distance, sticky="w")

                            elif (host[0:3] != "BCL" and host[0:3] != "PAD" and host[0:6] !="MASTER"):
                                ip_label = tk.Label(linea_frame, text=ip, fg="black", font=("Arial", 10, "bold"))
                                ip_label.grid(row=idy + 1, column=idx+1, padx=5, pady=distance, sticky="w")

                        status_frame = tk.Frame(linea_frame, width=25, height=25, bg=status_color)
                        status_frame.grid(row=idy + 1, column=idx+3, padx=5, pady=distance, sticky="e")

                    linea_label.grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=idx+3,padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")
            print("UPDATE DONE")
        except tk.TclError:
            print("error")
            return self.update_interface
        
    def auto_change_tab(self):
        self.num_tabs = self.tab_control.index("end")
        self.counter +=1
        if self.num_tabs > 1:
            current_tab_index = self.tab_control.index("current")
            next_tab_index = (current_tab_index + 1) % self.num_tabs
            self.tab_control.select(next_tab_index)
        if next_tab_index == 1:
            time.sleep(self.time/(2*self.time))
        self.root.after(self.time, self.auto_change_tab)
```

I think that the problem could be that this function is designed for create a new tab's and delete the old ones but i'm not sure

I expect that program don't crash

Comment: At least one problem might be because you're not using threading correctly, though it's hard to tell if this is intentional or not. `threading.Thread(target = self.update_interface())` will immediately call `self.update_interface()` in the current thread and pass the result to `threading.Thread`.

Comment: In these case, I call the function with threading, I make some modifications to resolve these problem, my first theory about the continous forget about tabs and create new ones was correct and I solve partially the problem, now the problem is that if I make the updates in the same tabs i destroy the old ones and create others, theoretically the  destruction of the old widgets should release the RAM memory, but it doesn't. The program at de begin uses 70MB of RAM after 5 hours to check the stability was using 2500MB, so for any one reason the program doesn't release the RAM

Comment: Why are you destroying the old widgets and creating new, instead of just reconfiguring the new? Also, are you calling `destroy` on the widget? You don't call `destroy` anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: Because is easer create the structure again that modify all widgets every time you have an update, also I was calling destroy all object because I was thinking that object were destroyed but even uses part of memory of the system, but I solved that problem, now I realise that the RAM problem it's for other function, that have to be with threading. Y will try to put that function solved in the next comment.

Comment: '            for pos_tab, seccion in enumerate(data):
                nombre_seccion = seccion["nombre"]
                lineas = seccion["lineas"]
                if pos_tab < self.tab_control.index("end"):
                    tab_frame = self.tab_control.winfo_children()[pos_tab]
                    # Elimina todos los widgets dentro del marco de la pestaña
                    for line_frame in tab_frame.winfo_children():
                        for widget in line_frame.winfo_children():
                            widget.destroy()
                        line_frame.destroy()'